# Translating degrees to SVG coordinates

Tags: php, jquery, svg

I am looking for a function either PHP or jQuery to translate degrees into SVG equivalent coordinates, if any, to ease up the conversions.

E.g.:

```
90 degree = x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%"

180 = x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%"
```

etc.. this is the question. I am looking for a function that will handle any conversion of degree from 0 to 360 into SVG coordinates.

I am looking into http://keith-wood.name/svg.html, and several other pages so far, but no luck.

A simple "no" will be very helpful also, if you are sure there is no such function exists. At least I will have to cease searching for something that do not exists :)

Any hint or reference will be very much appreciated. Thanks.

UPDATE:
A homework reference: http://www.zahniser.net/~russell/computer/index.php?title=Angle%20and%20Coordinates

Comment: You may get better luck searching for kml to svg conversions. There are some methods that do that, but none that I've seen via jquery or online, but software you have run locally on your machine. But then again, I never really looked that hard.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Still searching some relevant links on the right side as well.

Answer (score 3):

It is simple geometry. Have a look at the unit circle http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_circle

First convert your degrees to radians with

```
radians = degrees * Pi / 180
x = cos(radians) // will give you the value of y fom -1 to 1
y = sin(radians) // will give you the value of x fom -1 to 1
```

it's available in all programming languages I know, just choose the syntax that fits yours.

Comment: Thanks, great hint. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're working with the `<line>` element. You could use the [`transform`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#TransformAttribute) attribute to `rotate` the `<line>` by a specified degree. This is much simpler than calculating the values by hand.